Mix Ecto.Setup returning Postgrex.Protocol error "password authentication failed for user"
I'm new to Phoenix/Elixir and Docker.
I've been following a tutorial on YouTube where we set up PostgreSQL in a Docker Desktop container and configure it with credentials, then are supposed to plug-in said credentials to our Elixir project dev.exs file. I've done all the above and when I run mix ecto.setup (or ecto.create) I get the following output:
11:50:08.883 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.188.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "backend_stuff"

11:50:08.920 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.196.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "backend_stuff"
** (Mix) The database for ElixirGist.Repo couldn't be created: killed

Here is my dev.exs file:
config :elixir_gist, ElixirGist.Repo,
  username: "backend_stuff",
  password: "WAOdktQ3rPbPSK3kqPQpask1",
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: "5432",
  database: "elixir_gist_dev",
  stacktrace: true,
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10

I've tried accessing the Docker container (bs_db) and have successfully authenticated with the credentials above, so it's not the credentials that are the problem. At ChatGPT's suggestion, I also modified my "pg_hba.conf" and changed the "METHOD" to md5.
Another suggestion it made was to make the database myself in Docker but if I understand correctly, ecto.create / ecto.setup should handle this step so I'd like to figure out what's wrong there.

How are you actually starting the database?

@DavidMaze I think I setup a PostgreSQL instance in a Docker container, then I ran the container and from there I was of the understanding that Mix Ecto.Create would create the db

There's an option to set the database password and to create the database when you create the database container the very first time.  In this project I lean on that for database creation; I still need to run mix ecto.migrate but the database itself exists.

It would be helpful to share a link to the youtube video that you are following.
You should undo whatever ChatGPT told you to do. Chatbots often give very misleading or dangerous info, even "advanced" ones that are specifically made to help us write code. Show us the video you are following and we can help you.
My first guess would be that you need to set these environment variables (a.k.a. "env vars") in your postgres docker container: POSTGRES_USER POSTGRES_PASSWORD POSTGRES_DB.  How you do this depends on whether you are using plain docker or docker-compose?

It should not be that complicated ideally, it's a very standard process.
Try connecting the DB from any UI of postgres, like postico see if you are able to connect with these credentials.

When you say you are "accessing the Docker container"... how are you doing that?  Typically I check db credentials using a GUI app (or the psql CLI tool). If you can connect to the app's database using a tool like that, then the app should also be able to connect.  I just want to make sure you aren't doing something tricky like SSH'ing into the db's Docker container and then connecting to the db from WITHIN the Docker container, because that's not the connection that the app would use when connecting.
